# How can I redirect to "page not found" with MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some links in Google that I now no longer expect to work. All of the links look like this:

```
www.abc.com/xx/que=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Where x can be anything.

Can someone tell me how I can set up a route and controller action that will return a 404 to google? I guess I need to set it up with a mask that includes "que" but I am not so sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new route to *the top* of your global.asax. This will catch requests of the form `xx/que={anything}` using a regular expression to define the "que" argument.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PageNotFound", 
    "xx/{que}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" },
    new { que = "que=.*" });
```

This would also assume you have an `ErrorController` with action `NotFound` and corresponding view named `NotFound.aspx` in your /Views/Error/ directory.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some equivalent like return RedirectPermanent that I could use instead of returning an error view?

Comment: @Timothy Sure just return a `RedirectPermanent(string url)` instead of the NotFound View. So if you wanted to redirect to Google, you could do `return RedirectPermanent("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: I am sorry David. I didn't word my question properly. What I was wondering is if there is a way I can do the return of a 404 error without going to another view like NotFound.aspx?

Comment: @Timothy If you really want to 404, you can just `throw new HttpException(404, "Your error message");`, but you should return some content from your site. So, use my answer and set the Response.StatusCode to 404 (I'll edit my answer) This will provide a better user experience.